# Two variables in awk commands

Tags: variables, awk

Basically I want to split lib1.vh according to the chromosome number (chr1, chr2,chr3...).
But seems in the awk commands there are two variables, and it doesn't work..

Plz see below:

```
cd /home/xug/scratch/mrfast/NA12891/
CHROM_NAME=`head -$c list_chr|tail -1`

cat lib1.vh|awk '{if ($2==$CHROM_NAME) print}'
```

Then what should I do? thx

Hi guys:
I do this way, and it works!

```
cat lib1.vh|awk -v src=$CHROM_NAME '{if ($2==src) print}' > lib1_$CHROM_NAME.vh
```

Comment: What does your input look like? What do you want your output to look like? Why `head -$c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHROM_NAME` is a *shell* variable, but `'single quoted strings'` do not get shell variable replacement.

Perhaps you meant:

```
cd /home/xug/scratch/mrfast/NA12891/
CHROM_NAME=`head -$c list_chr|tail -1`

cat lib1.vh|awk "{if (\$2==$CHROM_NAME) print}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables appear as elements of the ENVIRON associative array. Instead of:

```
$CHROM_NAME
```

you want:

```
ENVIRON["CHROM_NAME"]
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer. :)

Comment: question is, is $CHROM_NAME environment variable? I don't think ENVIRON way is gonna work in this case...

Comment: Good point: I made the assumption Wang wanted to use the value defined in the previous line of the script. Maybe that's not right, but that line does create an environment variable named CHROM_NAME, which is accessed in the way I described. Perhaps Wang can clarify this?